# Dynamic Offset of Leaflet Popup

Tags: leaflet, style, animation

When a leaflet popup shows up, I would like to animate its offset value, so that the popup moves off to the right when it pops up. I imagine the codes goes something like this, but I haven't been able to figure it out:

```
layer.bindPopup(content,
{
offset: [x, y]
});

layer.on('click', function () {
setInterval(functionThatAnimatesxandy, 1000);
}
```

So apparently you can not animate the offset value. What might be a solution with CSS transitions?

Answer (score 1):

`offset` is a creation option and you cannot change it after creation. The proper way to change the popup's position is to use `popup.setLatLng(...)`. In the event listener you must pass the popup as the event context (as per the [docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#popup-on)). You will then be able to modify it inside the listener function.

```js
layer.bindPopup(content)

layer.on('click', function() {
  setInterval(functionThatAnimatesXAndY, 1000)
}, layer.getPopup()) // Pass the popup as the context
```

And then in your function you could do something like this:

```js
functionThatAnimatesXAndY(popup) {
  ... // here you can use popup.getLatLng() and popup.setLatLng(...)
}
```

Comment: That said, you could probably experiment with [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) on the actual screen coordinates of your popup.

Comment: There is a big difference between setting offset and setting position with coordinates, that should be mentioned in the answer. Offset is constant regardless of zoom, changing the coordinates is very much dependent on zoom. What seems a big offset at zoom 10, will be practically the same coordinate at zoom 2.

Comment: @TomazicM So offset as `Point(x,y)` is actually screen coordinates too, not geographic coordinates?

Comment: Exactly, it's offset in pixels from the `[lat, lng]` position.

Answer (score 1):

Since popup `div` container already has several CSS classes and popup offset is done through HTML `style` attribute (`left` and `bottom` properties), I don't see a way of animating popup with CSS transitions.

But there is as a way by using popup `className` option just to get access to popup container and then changing it's `style.left` property dynamically using `setTimeout` function. Popup `className` value can be anything not conflicting with other classes and does not need to exist. At the end of the animation popup offset has to be set to the new value so it's taken into account when popup is redrawn at map zoom.

Below is complete working example where popup is shifted to the right by 20 pixels after being displayed:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([52.2858, 5.78682], 14);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>',
  maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

var myPopup = L.popup({
  className: 'myPopup',
  offset: [0, 0]
});

myPopup.setContent(     
  '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus volutpat non elit at pretium.</p>'
  + '<p>Curabitur iaculis dolor interdum nulla dignissim, iaculis pretium nisl vulputate. Donec eget eros sapien.</p>'
);

function animatePopup(popup, offset, step, currentOffset) {
  var popupElement = document.getElementsByClassName(popup.options.className)[0];
  var left = parseInt(popupElement.style.left);
  if (typeof currentOffset == 'undefined') currentOffset = 0;
  popupElement.style.left = left + step + 'px';
  offset -= step;
  if (offset > 0) {
    currentOffset += step;
    setTimeout(animatePopup, 30, popup, offset, step, currentOffset);
    }
  else {
    var bottom = parseInt(popupElement.style.bottom);
    popup.options.offset = [currentOffset, -bottom];
  }
}

map.on('popupopen', function (evt) {
  animatePopup(evt.popup, 20, 1);
});

myPopup.setLatLng(map.getCenter()).openOn(map);
```